# VB coded macro not running in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am having difficulty running a Macro in PowerPoint. I would like the macro to set tables in the slide to a height of 14cm. This is my code:

```
Sub AdjustTableHeight()
    Dim tbl As ListObject 
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1") ' 

    ' Set the height of the table to 14 cm
    tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium1" '
    tbl.TableObject.RowSizing = xlFixedHeight
    tbl.TableObject.Height = Application.CentimetersToPoints(14)
End Sub
```

However when I run it nothing happens

Comment: Office macros are written in VBA, not VB.NET.

Comment: Please use the preview provided and don't submit your question if the formatting is a mess. It is incumbent upon you to make it as easy as possible for us to help you, which includes making your question and any code it contains as readable as possible.

Comment: It is `Excel VBA` code. For sure, you can't run it with PowerPoint. What's your goal?

Answer (score 1):

The code on OP is `Excel VBA` code. For sure, you can't run it with PowerPoint.

Below code (PowerPoint VBA) sets table (`data table` and PowerPoint `table`) height in PPT active window.

*Credit to **Steve Rindsberg***

Note: There is no definite way to identify if an object is an `data table` or PowerPoint `table` object. A potential workaround is to check for the data table's name.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub SetTableHeight()
    Dim slide As slide, tbl As Table
    Dim shp As Shape, bNoTab As Boolean
    tabHeight = 14
    bNoTab = True
    ' Get the current active slide
    Set slide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.slide
    For Each shp In slide.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTable Then
            bNoTab = False
            shp.Height = tabHeight * 28.35
        End If
    Next
    If bNoTab Then
        MsgBox "There are no tables on the slide."
    Else
        MsgBox "Done"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When I use the above code I get the message: 'There are no tables on the slide' even though my slide has a table. The table has been added as a data table i.e. not from PowerPoint itself. When I select the table and look in the selection pane the table is definitely there.

Comment: The goal is to make the table un my slide fit onto the slide as at the moment when it is added it is much larger than the slide itself.

Comment: How would I edit my questions in the future so that they are in the grey box/ in preview like the above

Comment: Not sure how to reply, please see above comments @taller_ExcelHome @ 
jmcilhinney

Comment: I am now not getting the message 'there are no tables on the slide' but when I run the macros the table doesn't edit @taller_ExcelHome

Comment: create a new pptx and insert a table, copy and run the code

Comment: >> The table has been added as a data table i.e. not from PowerPoint itself. << The code above is looking for PowerPoint tables. "Data table" doesn't tell us anything about what it really is or where it came from or how